# How to open OneNote notebook from OneDrive group?

Tags: internet-explorer, onedrive, onenote, 8.1-update-1

I have updated to Windows Phone 8.1 Update 1 through developer preview and now I can't open notebooks that are part of OneDrive group.
In previous versions of Windows Phone I used to browse to the notebooks in the browser and when clicking on it would open it (and bookmark it) in the OneNote app. However, now when I try clicking on it in the browser it does nothing.

Any idea how to open this type of notebooks on Windows Phone?

Comment: I managed to open some by going to the OneDrive app and finding them in the "recent" tab.

Comment: You should rewrite your comment as an answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**

- Open MS Office in Windows phone
- Tap on OneDrive from places
- Tap on Documents
- There you will find your notebooks

**Option 2:**

- Open Onenote
- On top left where you see the arrows, tap on that
- You can navigate easily

Comment: please consider giving an upvote as I only started and need some reputation to kick off

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "take"?

Comment: Open or tap on the icon or folder